# Using Javascript FileWriter with minimal use of closures

Tags: javascript, html5, optimization

I'm currently writing a WebGL HTML5 game, and large part of the game initialization involved loading assets streamed over a websocket, and saving them to disk using the FileSystem API.

As part of optimizing the code, we're trying to eliminate as many memory allocations as we can, which means cutting down on the use of closures, object/array creation during the main game loop and so on.

One of the biggest uses of closures left is our interaction with the FileSystem API, namely the part where we write the assets to disk:

```
//Write file to disk
directory.getFile(
    filename,
    CREATE_TRUE,
    function(fileEntry) {
        fileEntry.createWriter(
            function(fileWriter) {
                fileWriter.onwriteend=function(e) {
                    finishedRequest(filename);
                    if (onSuccess!==undefined) onSuccess(filename);
                };
                fileWriter.onerror=function(e) {
                    finishedRequest(filename);
                    if (onError!==undefined) onError(filename, "Write error: "+directoryRoot+"/"+filename);
                };
                var dataBlob=new Blob([new Uint8Array(data)]);
                if (append) fileWriter.seek(fileWriter.length);
                fileWriter.write(dataBlob,"application/octet-stream");
             },
             function(e) {
                 finishedRequest(filename);
                 if (onError!==undefined) onError(filename,"File writer creation error: "+directoryRoot+"/"+filename:"");
             } 
        );
    },
    function(e) {
        finishedRequest(filename);
        if (onError!==undefined) onError(filename,DEVELOPMENT_MODE?"File not found: "+directoryRoot+"/"+filename:"");
    }
);
```

As you can see, this code involves the creation of something like six new closures for every file write, which isn't the greatest when we're trying to cut down on memory allocation.

I initially tried to pull each of the closures out into standalone functions, but obviously I then needed to be able to get references to things like the filename and onSuccess callback function from those standalone functions (whereas previously they would have been able to have access to them from their outer closures):

```
...
fileWriter.onwriteend=onFileWrite;
...

function onFileWrite=function(e) {
    finishedRequest(filename);  //filename needs to be retrieved from somewhere...
    if (onSuccess!==undefined) onSuccess(filename);
}
```

The problem is that the onFileWrite callback is only supplied with the event object, which contains a reference to the target fileWriter, but nothing higher.  Crucially, there seems to be no way to link the fileEntry with the fileWriter that it creates, as the createWriter callback only gets given the FileWriter object - with no meta data about what created it.

My question is this: is it possible to rewrite this without using quite some many closures - or ideally none at all?

**Edit**: I'm convinced that it is (unfortunately) impossible to do this without creating some kind of container for the details of the request, be it a new function whose closure includes the request details, or a new object whose properties have the details.  So, this question really then becomes about the best way to achieve the file write with the smallest amount of memory churn.

Comment: I'm going to migrate it in a few minutes, but would you like to award the bounty first so it doesn't get lost on the way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you will always need some closures, but you can limit what they carry.
This was your example:

```
...
fileWriter.onwriteend=onFileWrite;
...

function onFileWrite=function(e) {
    finishedRequest(filename);  //filename needs to be retrieved from somewhere...
    if (onSuccess!==undefined) onSuccess(filename);
}
```

I guess that your intention was to define a function for each case and then assign it.
So your example transforms into this (I'm just reorganizing your code and fixing a function declaration).

```
var onFileWrite = function(e) {
    finishedRequest(filename);  //filename needs to be retrieved from somewhere...
    if (onSuccess!==undefined) onSuccess(filename);
}

...
fileWriter.onwriteend=onFileWrite;
...
```

This is actually an optimization because you can reuse things, the problem now is how do we get the filename. Well you can write a function that gets the filename and return a new function that only has the filename in its closure and nothing else. Like this:

```
var onFileWrite = function(filename) {
    return function(e) {
        finishedRequest(filename);
        if (onSuccess!==undefined) onSuccess(filename);
    }
}

...
fileWriter.onwriteend=onFileWrite(filename);
...
```

Note that this way you just pass what you need, variables, functions but always controlling the closure "size".

Hope it helps you, good luck with the game!

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach here would be

- Create a FileWriter wrapper which exposes the functionality through a (jQuery?) Deferred pattern http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/
- Use this wrapper in your code instead of a pure FileWriter callbacks
- Then you could avoid clousure mess by using `promise()`, `success()`, `error()` and friends to write more linear code instead of resulting to nesting
- Note that other libraries also provide Deferred implementation (underscore.js, etc.)

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/wrangle-async-tasks-with-jquery-promises/

Sorry I did not find a better tutorial how to convert existing closures to use Deferred object.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I'm concerned that this doesn't remove the closures, but rather pushes them into the wrapper that exposes the Deferred pattern.  Though this undoubtedly will make the code neater, it doesn't help with my goal of removing the closures due to the associated memory allocation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could rewrite this without using *closures*.

In your case, all callbacks are called on system events. If you specify a number of standalone functions, which are not changed during runtime, and use those functions as callbacks, you can't really know inside those functions in which state a program was, when you initiated async call.

You have following variables that specify a state: `filename, onError, onSuccess, append, directoryRoot, data`. When you initiated first `directory.getFile` call, you know what the state is. If those variables are not changed on runtime, then you could just store them globally. I understande the issue is, that each time you have different values for those variables.

So, on each `directory.getFile` call all those callbacks should be modified to store those variables somehow. You could avoid *closures* usage, if by *closure* is meant a lexical scope of outter function. For this purpose, `Function.prototype.bind` could be used. Here is modified code:

```
window.fileWriterSuccess = function (e) {
    this.finishedRequest(this.filename);

    if (this.onSuccess !== undefined) this.onSuccess(this.filename);
};

window.fileWriterError = function (e) {
    this.finishedRequest(this.filename);

    if (this.onError !== undefined) this.onError(this.filename, "Write error: " + this.directoryRoot + "/" + this.filename);
};

window.createWriterSuccess = function (fileWriter) {
    fileWriter.onwriteend = fileWriterSuccess.bind(this);

    fileWriter.onerror = fileWriterError.bind(this);

    var dataBlob = new Blob([new Uint8Array(this.data)]);

    if (this.append) fileWriter.seek(fileWriter.length);

    fileWriter.write(dataBlob, "application/octet-stream");

};

window.createWriterError = function(e) {
    this.finishedRequest(this.filename);

    if (this.onError !== undefined) this.onError(this.filename, "File writer creation error: " + this.directoryRoot + "/" + this.filename : "");
};

window.getFileSuccess = function (fileEntry) {
    fileEntry.createWriter(createWriterSuccess.bind(obj), createWriterError.bind(obj));
};

window.getFileError = function (e) {
    this.finishedRequest(this.filename);

    if (this.onError !== undefined) this.onError(this.filename, DEVELOPMENT_MODE ? "File not found: " + this.directoryRoot + "/" + this.filename : "");
};

...
/* Inside some function call */

var _obj = {
    filename: filename,
    onError: onError,
    onSuccess: onSuccess,
    append: append,
    directoryRoot: directoryRoot,
    data: data
};

directory.getFile(filename, CREATE_TRUE, getFileSuccess.bind(_obj), getFileError.bind(_obj));
```

So, an `_obj` is created to store a program state, which is then is used to create callbacks. No *closures* are created, as there are no explicit function literals in the code. But on each call a number of functions which assigned `_obj` context are created.

Comment: Cheers for your suggestion - I'd not encountered the use of .bind before.  However, I'm worried that all this does is hide the creation of new function scopes behind the bind calls, as each one creates a new function - something my code is already doing and something I'm wanting to avoid.  Unfortunately, using bind also adds the overhead of creating a new `obj` for every request, so it's actually worse for memory churn than my version.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach with very shallow closures, and makes use of prototype to conserve memory.

```
function SuperFileWriter(filename, directoryRoot, option, data) {
    this.filename = filename;
    this.directoryRoot = directoryRoot;
    this.option = option;
    this.data = data;
    this.fileEntry = null;
    this.fileWriter = null;
    this.start = function() {
        directory.getFile(filename, option, this.onSuccess, this.onFail)
    };
};

SuperFileWriter.prototype.onSuccess = function(fileEntry) {
    this.fileEntry = fileEntry;
    this.fileEntry.createWriter(onCreateWriterSuccess, onCreateWriterFail)
}

SuperFileWriter.prototype.onFail = function(e) {
    finishedRequest(this.filename);
    if (onError!==undefined) 
        onError(filename, DEVELOPMENT_MODE ? "File not found: "+this.directoryRoot+"/"+this.filename : "");
}

SuperFileWriter.prototype.onCreateWriterSuccess = function(fileWriter) {
    this.fileWriter = fileWriter;
    this.fileWriter.onwriteend = this.prototype.onWriteEnd;
    this.fileWriter.onerror = this.prototype.onWriteError;

    var dataBlob=new Blob([new Uint8Array(this.data)]);
    if (append) fileWriter.seek(this.fileWriter.length);
    this.fileWriter.write(dataBlob,"application/octet-stream");
}

SuperFileWriter.prototype.onCreateWriterFail = function(e) {
     finishedRequest(this.filename);
     if (onError!==undefined) 
        onError(this.filename,"File writer creation error: "+this.directoryRoot+"/"+this.filename);
} 

SuperFileWriter.prototype.onWriteEnd = function(e) {
    finishedRequest(this.filename);
    if (onSuccess!==undefined) onSuccess(this.filename);
};


SuperFileWriter.prototype.onWriteError = function(e) {
    finishedRequest(this.filename);
    if (onError!==undefined) 
        onError(this.filename, "Write error: "+this.directoryRoot+"/"+this.filename);
}
```

And then to call it...

```
var sfw = new SuperFileWriter(...);
sfw.start()
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work - when onSuccess is called, `this` points to `window`, rather than my `superFileWriter` instance, so I can't retrieve any of the fields from it.

Comment: did you use 'new'?

Comment: Indeed I did - calling `start` is fine, `this` points to what you'd expect, but the callbacks just regard the passed-in function as standalone, so don't bind `this` to my `SuperFileWriter` object.  Tis a shame, I thought this was going to be the neatest solution.